# The nested query does not have the appropriate keys

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, join

Firstly I have a function which takes 2 parameters( longitude, latitude).

```
  RETURNS TABLE 
  AS
  RETURN 
   (
    select dbo.GeoCalculateDistance (@lat1Degrees,@lon1Degrees,Latitude,Longitude) as    Distance, PKRestaurantId as PkKeyId from StRestaurant
   )
```

And as you realise, I have a table that called StRestaurant. In this table I have 4 columns(PkRestaurantId, RegionId , Longitude, Latitude).

And, I need a method that takes 4 parameters.

```
 public List<RestaurantDetailDto> GetRestaurant(int regionid, decimal latitude, decimal longitude, OrderType orderType)
    {}
```

This method will give the restauants around me. But if I want to systematize this list with distance, I must join my Restaurant table and the function. Here is my query.

```
            var query = from restaurant in context.StRestaurant
                        join distance in context.CalculateDistanceTable(latitude, longitude) on restaurant.PKRestaurantId equals distance.PkKeyId
                        where restaurant.FKRegionId == regionid 
                        select new
                            {
                                Restaurant = restaurant,
                                DistanceTable = distance,
                            };
```

And then I am checking the orderType,

```
      switch (orderType)
            {
                case OrderType.Distance:
                    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.DistanceTable.Distance);
                    break;

            // and the anothers
            }
```

Lastly, I am trying to take this list as;

```
      var queryResult = query.ToList();
```

All the time I took this error :

**The nested query does not have the appropriate keys.**

I also try the above query but it return with the same error :s

```
    var query = context.StRestaurant.Where(x => x.FKRegionId == regionid && x.IsActive).Join(
                context.CalculateDistanceTable(latitude, longitude),
                restaurant => restaurant.PKRestaurantId,
                result => result.PkKeyId,
                (restaurant, result) => new
                    {
                        Restaurant = restaurant,
                        MinumumPackagePrice = restaurant.StRestaurantRegionRelation.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FKRestaurantId == restaurant.PKRestaurantId).MinumumPackageCharge,
                        DistanceTable = result,
                        RestaurantImage = restaurant.StRestaurantImage.Where(x => x.IsDefault && x.FKRestaurantId == restaurant.PKRestaurantId),
                    }
                );
```

Please help!!

Comment: When you get this error?

Comment: I get this error when I try to make below : var response = query.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before when doing an .Include() on the result. I imagine your projection (in the second example) might be doing this internally. Could you add this to the first part?

In this case, I've had to add the `.Include()` on the source table:

`from a in context.A.Include("relationship")
     join b in context.MyFunction(...)
     ...`

Answer (score 0):

There are a some things that you can try here. First, rewrite your SQL function so that it has a primary key:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistanceTable 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @lat1Degrees float, 
    @lon1Degrees float
)
RETURNS 
@RestaurantDistances TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    PkKeyId int NOT NULL primary key, 
    Distance float NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RestaurantDistances
    SELECT        dbo.GeoCalculateDistance(@lat1Degrees, @lon1Degrees, Latitude, Longitude) AS Distance, PKRestaurantId AS PkKeyId
    FROM            StRestaurant

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Also, you can try changing your LINQ join to use anonymous types to perform the join.

```
var query = from restaurant in context.StRestaurant
            join distance in context.CalculateDistanceTable(latitude, longitude) on new { Key = restaurant.PKRestaurantId } equals new { Key = distance.PkKeyId }
                    where restaurant.FKRegionId == regionid 
                    select new
                        {
                            Restaurant = restaurant,
                            DistanceTable = distance,
                        };
```

If neither one of these helps let me know and I'll try to update this answer as appropriate.

Comment: Let me try it on Monday. I will let you know if these will help or not. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @doganilker Same error message with these or something different?